# Function differentiable in the complex sense

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $G$ be a connected open, contained in $\mathbb{C}$, $f=u+iv$ a differentiable function in the complex sense in $G$ and $\bar{v}:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a constant function. Prove that the function $u+i\bar{v}$ is differentiable in the complex sense in $G$ if and only if $u-\bar{v}$ is constant in $G$.

Comment: "related open"?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Adds new meaning to neighbourhood.

Comment: Tip : Instead of writing "differentiable function in the complex sense", one can just write "complex-differentiable function".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Cauchy-Riemann equations.